# Webextension mouse click command API (mouse click shortcuts)?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

Both Firefox and Chrome seem to list https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands as their supported API for providing keyboard shortcuts for extensions.

Is there a way to incorporate mouse buttons (left click/right click) into these keyboard shortcuts, ideally with some recognition of the context?

For example, creating a custom keyboard shortcut when clicking a link, to perform some action, like "on Alt-Shift-Left_click of a link, do X".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the commands interface doesn't support that. Instead, for the example you give, you'd need to add a content script that includes a click handler. In the click handler, the [mouse event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) includes flags for which modifier keys were pressed which can be checked to determine if the action should happen.

Comment: Sounds like you mean I would need to attach this handler to all potential elements on the page the user could perform this action on? Seems a little invasive to me, I was hoping for something a bit more standard like the right click context-menus api. Makes sense though that that wouldn't be the case.

Comment: @Nick Generally, you'd only need to attach the handler to `body` since click events bubble up the DOM. However this wouldn't be able to catch all click events since it's possible for other javascript to prevent a particular event from bubbling. But it's likely to cover 90%+ of your needs.